# emacs useless auto-indentation once invoking text-scale

Tags: emacs

I have a problem on using text-scale-increase.
When invoking this function, Emacs inserts a certain indetation sometimes.
Please let me know if you have a solution for this.
[image]

Comment: The question is unclear. Please consider providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce what you see, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), saying at each relevant step what you see and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: Hi Drew, I just invoked text-scale-increase few times and it expanded the gap between linenumber and my text.